# XML Read in Informatica BDM 10.5.3

Tags: informatica, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am trying to real XML file in Informatica BDM and load this in Teradata table. For this I have created a PDO with complex file data object with below configuration. XML file is placed at my local path.

1. Resource format: XML
2. Choose XML file from my local path

Complex file data object is created with 2 columns Data and filename. Data column name has type binary and filename has string.

Then, I created hierarchy to relational transformation and chose the XML file to parse it. I have provided the same file as schema and I can see it is parsed successfully

In mapping, I dragged the complex file data object PDO and then hierarchy to relational transformation and then target PDO.

In my complex file data object, I have mentioned File Format = Custom Input.

When I run data viewer, it says file does not exist at my local path, however it is available. Below is the error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So now the latest status is, mapping ran successfully but data is not loaded. In logs it says Error parsing element attribute in Hierarchy to relational transformation

Comment: I have modified the mapping. The source PDO is now a flat file which contains the path of my XML file. And then Hierarchy to Relational transformation which will read the file from the path provided by source.

New Error:
Unable to read the document on hierarchy to relational transformation

Comment: The error sugests that you try to parse a flat file, rather than XML. The source should be XML file, not a flat file with path.

Comment: The source path contains the xml file path. In logs I have checked it is successfully picking that file path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment that I have updated the mapping by adding source PDO as flatfile source, then added XML file path to the flatfile source, but still having the error:

"Unable to real input document"

From logs it had been verified that XML is read successfully from the flat file path so there is no issue in that.

For hierarchy to relational transformation, in Output Mapping, you can see there are 2 areas, one is transformation input on the left and other is transformation output on the right. I need only few tags from my XML and I have updated it to only get that tag as my root from Choose Hierarchy option on right hand side. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

Due to this, there is a mismatch between the XML read from source and transformation in hierarchy to relational transformation.

To resolve this I have selected the main tag as root from my XML and they input and transformation input/output are synchronized. This change had resolved my issue and I am now successfully able to load data into the Teradata tables